# How can I undo the changes after compiling a package?

Tags: compiling, make

Let's say that I have build a package using the typical method

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and then I would like to uninstall this package. There is no any uninstall script. How can I revert my system back to the state it was before do the building/compiling ?

Comment: does the Makefile have an uninstall target?  e.g. does `make uninstall` work for that package?

Comment: This is why system binary packages exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much screwed up you are unlucky and the make file doesn't offer a uninstall target (ie. `make uninstall`) you must track and see what files it installed/modified. Doing `make -n install` will print all the files as it will be writing them to the disk.

Another method is running `make install` without root permissions. It will throw all the write errors and then you could just remove them. There are other Makefiles that will write out a `install_manifest.txt` file, which you can just iterate.

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21086180/792066